# The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection - Does using() {} cheat?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

While using the `using() {}` (sic) blocks as shown below, and assuming that `cmd1` does not live beyond the scope of the first `using() {}` block, why should the second block throw an exception with the message

> The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Does it mean that resources and/or handles - including the parameters (`SqlParameterCollection`) - attached to `cmd1` are not released when its destroyed at the end of the block?

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    var parameters = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@ProductId", SqlDbType.Int ) };

    using(var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductId = @ProductId"))
    {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.Add(parameter);                
        }
        // cmd1.Parameters.Clear(); // uncomment to save your skin!
    }

    using (var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Review FROM ProductReviews WHERE ProductId = @ProductId"))
    {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Doing cmd1.Parameters.Clear() just before the last brace of the first **using() {}** block will save you from the exception (and possible embarrassment).

If you need to reproduce you can use the following scripts to create the objects:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    ProductId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ProductName nvarchar(32) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE ProductReviews
(
    ReviewId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ProductId int NOT NULL,
    Review nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, but that fix didn't work.  Frustrating.  And I'm only using a single cmd object, not reused.  It's wrapped in an async retry loop, so it's probably the same root cause just not avoided the same way.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I suspect that `SqlParameter` "knows" which command it's part of, and that that information isn't cleared when the command is disposed, but *is* cleared when you call `command.Parameters.Clear()`.

Personally I think I'd avoid reusing the objects in the first place, but it's up to you :)

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that is the case. It would also mean the the SqlParameter is associating itself with a disposed object which I am not sure its a good thing

Comment: @JohnGathogo: Well, it's associated with an object which is disposed *after* the association has been formed. It's not ideal, certainly.

Comment: A note for others. I had to perform the `Clear` before exiting the first `using` block. Doing it when entering my 2nd `using` block still threw this error.

Answer (score 12):

Adding cmd.Parameters.Clear(); after execution should be fine.

Comment: Literally most simple, usable and clean solution out there. Thanks a ton mate.

Answer (score 9):

Using blocks do not ensure that an object is "destroyed", simply that the `Dispose()` method is called.  What that actually does is up to the specific implementation and in this case it clearly does not empty the collection. The idea is to ensure that unmanaged resources that would not be cleaned up by the garbage collector are correctly disposed. As the Parameters collection is not an unmanaged resource it is not entirely suprising it is not cleared by the dispose method.

Answer (score 5):

I faced this particular error because I was using the same SqlParameter objects as part of a SqlParameter collection for calling a procedure multiple times. The reason for this error IMHO is that the SqlParameter objects are associated to a particular SqlParameter Collection and you can't use the same SqlParameter objects to create a new SqlParameter collection.

So, instead of this:

```cs
var param1 = new SqlParameter{ DbType = DbType.String, ParameterName = param1,Direction = ParameterDirection.Input , Value = "" };
var param2 = new SqlParameter{ DbType = DbType.Int64, ParameterName = param2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input , Value = 100};

SqlParameter[] sqlParameter1 = new[] { param1, param2 };

ExecuteProc(sp_name, sqlParameter1);

/*ERROR : 
SqlParameter[] sqlParameter2 = new[] { param1, param2 };
ExecuteProc(sp_name, sqlParameter2);
*/
```

Do this:

```cs
var param3 = new SqlParameter{ DbType = DbType.String, ParameterName = param1, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input , Value = param1.Value };
var param4 = new SqlParameter{ DbType = DbType.Int64, ParameterName = param2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input , Value = param2.Value};

SqlParameter[] sqlParameter3 = new[] { param3, param4 };

ExecuteProc(sp_name, sqlParameter3);
```

Answer (score 4):

`using` defines a scope, and does the automatic call of `Dispose()` for which we love it.

A reference falling out of scope will not make the object itself "disappear" if another object has a reference to it, which in this case will be the case for `parameters` having a reference to `cmd1`.

Answer (score 2):

I have Also got the same issue Thanks @Jon, based on that I gave example.

When I called the below function in which 2 times same sqlparameter passed. In the first database call, it was called properly, but in the second time, it was give the above error.

```
    public Claim GetClaim(long ClaimId)
    {
        string command = "SELECT * FROM tblClaim "
            + " WHERE RecordStatus = 1 and ClaimId = @ClaimId and ClientId =@ClientId";
        List<SqlParameter> objLSP_Proc = new List<SqlParameter>(){
                new SqlParameter("@ClientId", SessionModel.ClientId),
                new SqlParameter("@ClaimId", ClaimId)
            };

        DataTable dt = GetDataTable(command, objLSP_Proc);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        List<Claim> list = TableToList(dt);

        command = "SELECT * FROM tblClaimAttachment WHERE RecordStatus = 1 and ClaimId = @ClaimId and ClientId =@ClientId";

        DataTable dt = GetDataTable(command, objLSP_Proc); //gives error here, after add `sqlComm.Parameters.Clear();` in GetDataTable (below) function, the error resolved.


        retClaim.Attachments = new ClaimAttachs().SelectMany(command, objLSP_Proc);
        return retClaim;
    }
```

**This is the common DAL function**

```
       public DataTable GetDataTable(string strSql, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = this.GetConnection())
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSql, connection);

                    if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
                    {
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                    }

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Clear(); //this added and error resolved
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
                throw;
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exception because I had failed to instantiate a parameter object.  I thought it was complaining about two procedures having parameters with the same name.  It was complaining about the same parameter being added twice.

```
            Dim aParm As New SqlParameter()
            aParm.ParameterName = "NAR_ID" : aParm.Value = hfCurrentNAR_ID.Value
            m_daNetworkAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(aParm)
            aParm = New SqlParameter
            Dim tbxDriveFile As TextBox = gvNetworkFileAccess.Rows(index).FindControl("tbxDriveFolderFile")
            aParm.ParameterName = "DriveFolderFile" : aParm.Value = tbxDriveFile.Text
            m_daNetworkAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(aParm)
            **aParm = New SqlParameter()**  <--This line was missing.
            Dim aDDL As DropDownList = gvNetworkFileAccess.Rows(index).FindControl("ddlFileAccess")
            aParm.ParameterName = "AccessGranted" : aParm.Value = aDDL.Text
            **m_daNetworkAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(aParm)** <-- The error occurred here.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**
I was executing a SQL Server stored procedure from C# when I encountered this issue:

> Exception message [The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.]

**Cause**
I was passing 3 parameters to my stored procedure. I added the

```
param = command.CreateParameter();
```

only once altogether. I should have added this line for each parameter, it means 3 times altogether.

```
DbCommand command = CreateCommand(ct.SourceServer, ct.SourceInstance, ct.SourceDatabase);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "[ETL].[pGenerateScriptToCreateIndex]";

DbParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@IndexTypeID";
param.DbType = DbType.Int16;
param.Value = 1;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = command.CreateParameter(); --This is the line I was missing
param.ParameterName = "@SchemaName";
param.DbType = DbType.String;
param.Value = ct.SourceSchema;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = command.CreateParameter(); --This is the line I was missing
param.ParameterName = "@TableName";
param.DbType = DbType.String;
param.Value = ct.SourceDataObjectName;
command.Parameters.Add(param);

dt = ExecuteSelectCommand(command);
```

**Solution**
Adding the following line of code for each parameter

```
param = command.CreateParameter();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it!

```
        ILease lease = (ILease)_SqlParameterCollection.InitializeLifetimeService();
        if (lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
        {
            lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            lease.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            lease.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            lease.Renew(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you're using EntityFramework

I also had this same exception. In my case, I was calling SQL via a EntityFramework DBContext. The following is my code, and how I fixed it.

### Broken Code

```
string sql = "UserReport @userID, @startDate, @endDate";

var sqlParams = new Object[]
{
    new SqlParameter { ParameterName= "@userID", Value = p.UserID, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, IsNullable = true }
    ,new SqlParameter { ParameterName= "@startDate", Value = p.StartDate, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, IsNullable = true }
    ,new SqlParameter { ParameterName= "@endDate", Value = p.EndDate, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, IsNullable = true }
};

IEnumerable<T> rows = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql,parameters);

foreach(var row in rows) {
    // do something
}

// the following call to .Count() is what triggers the exception
if (rows.Count() == 0) {
    // tell user there are no rows
}
```

**Note:** the above call to `SqlQuery<T>()` actually returns a `DbRawSqlQuery<T>`, which implements `IEnumerable`

### Why does calling .Count() throw the exception?

I haven't fired up SQL Profiler to confirm, but I suspect that `.Count()` is triggering another call to SQL Server, and internally it is reusing the same `SQLCommand` object and trying to re-add the duplicate parameters.

### Solution / Working Code

I added a counter inside my `foreach`, so that I could keep a row count without having to call `.Count()`

```
int rowCount = 0;

foreach(var row in rows) {
    rowCount++
    // do something
}

if (rowCount == 0) {
    // tell user there are no rows
}
```

### Afterthough

My project is probably using an old version of EF. The newer version may have fixed this internal bug by clearing the parameters, or disposing of the `SqlCommand` object.

Or maybe, there are explicit instructions that tell developers not to call `.Count()` after iterating a `DbRawSqlQuery`, and I'm coding it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the exception for me was I was I had missed adding a new column to a user defined table type in my database.

I was adding a column to an existing table which also required updating the stored procedure that inserted data into that table.  But I didn't realize that the stored procedure was using a user defined table type that specified the layout of the table data being passed into that stored procedure.  So even though I had updated all references in my code, the stored procedure, and the table, the code was throwing this exception when calling the stored procedure. My guess is it incorrectly handling the extra column in such a way that it behaved like a duplicate parameter.