# Understanding 'The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following piece of code:

```
SqlParameter invidParam = new SqlParameter("@invid",obj.INVID);
SqlParameter prodParam = new SqlParameter("@prod", obj.PROD);
SqlParameter descrParam = new SqlParameter("@descr", obj.DESCR);      
SqlParameter qtyParam = new SqlParameter("@qty", 1);

if(SessionHelper.TryGetSession("curUser",out User user))
{
    SqlParameter useridParamCheck = new SqlParameter("@userid", user.Username);

    var queryResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("EXEC CheckIfAlreadyInPR#invid#userid @invid, @userid", invidParam, useridParamCheck);
    var qty = queryResult.FirstOrDefault();

    if (qty == 0)
    {
        SqlParameter useridParamInsert = new SqlParameter("@userid", user.Username);
        var insertResult = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("InsertIntoPR @invid, @prod, @descr, @userid, @qty", invidParam, prodParam, descrParam, useridParamInsert, qtyParam);
    }
    else if (qty > 0)
    {
        SqlParameter qtyParameter = new SqlParameter("@newqty", (qty + 1));
        SqlParameter userIdParamUpdate = new SqlParameter("@userid", user.Username);

        var updateResult = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UpdatePRQty#invid#userid#newqty @invid,@userid,@newqty",invidParam,userIdParamUpdate,qtyParameter);
    }
}
```

My program runs and hits an exception at the line `var insertResult = db...`

I am trying to understand which `SqlParameter` is already contained in another collection. Is it because the parameter `@userid` is already used in the previous stored procedure call ?

I declared the `SqlParameter("@userid")` 3 times, with  different variable names:

```
useridParamCheck, useridParamInsert, userIdParamUpdate
```

Did this cause the error because the name `@userid` is used? If I use `@userid1`, `@userid2`, `@userid3` will the problem be resolved? Or the `SqlParameter` that is already contained is some other SQL parameters that I declared above?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection - Does using() {} cheat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837762/the-sqlparameter-is-already-contained-by-another-sqlparametercollection-does-u)

Comment: You can't use the same instance of `SqlParamater` for two different sql-commands. Look for example at `invidParam`

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to suggest that `invidparam` is your problem parameter as it is the only parameter I can see that is used twice. Once in `db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("EXEC CheckIfAlreadyInPR#invid#userid @invid, @userid", invidParam, useridParamCheck);` and again in both instances of `db.Database.ExecuteCommand()`.

The error itself relates to an `SqlParameter` object being used multiple times rather than the same parameter name being used multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with the following code

```
  var p = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter{ParameterName = "@p0", SqlDbType 
  SqlDbType.DateTime ,Value = ut.ReadyByDate, };
  var nextTasksResults = db.Database.SqlQuery<nextTask>(sql2, p);
  var isAny = nextTaskResults.Any() // error
```

The work around was to send to an array and use that

```
  var nextTasks = nextTasksResults.ToArray();
  var isAny = nextTasks.Any();
```